# Javascript transpiler which is add this keyword automatically inside classes

Tags: javascript, this, transpiler

Please tell me somebody know some solution which make me I can left the this keywords from classes!
What I want is simple a transpiler which is inject the this keyword for every place where needed!

Example:

```
class CleanClass{ //Which I write
   constructor(){
     loveJs=null;
     setLoveJs(true);
   }

  setLoveJs(really=false){
    loveJs=really; 
  }
}

class CleanClass{ //Transpiled
   constructor(){
     this.loveJs=null;
     this.setLoveJs(true);
   }

  setLoveJs(really=false){
    this.loveJs=really; 
  }
}
```

Simply put the "this." to every neccesary place, I not want to write "this." 1000 times a day for god sake (I know it can cause rare problems I can handle that..). I can't find any existng solution, I can't believe no one ever thought about this? Do I must write for myself?

Obviously it need to watch local variables or functions, if a local variable exists not put the "this." before the variable name.

Thank you!

Comment: This does not exist and, due to the way javascript works, would not be possible to make without making a lot of assumptions. It's not clear from `loveJs=null` that you're assigning to an instance variable `loveJS` or perhaps one in another scope or perhaps a global variable or in a closure or... etc. I would recommend you just write `this`. If you *really* dislike this you could always use closure-based "constructors" instead (but don't)

Comment: "*I know it can cause rare problems. I can handle that.*" - no, `this` rarely causes problems. Though if it does, you cannot handle them when using the approach of omitting keywords.

Comment: Even Microsoft, the company behind C# and VB, when they created  Typescript left the behavior of `this` in the language. You will have to invent your own language that compiles to javascript if you really feel strongly about it. Alternatively you can use languages like Rust to compile to javascript or you can even use emscripten to compile C++ to javascript.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use functional programming and closures and abandon OO completely (at least the constructor). You don't need classes/constructors to build objects in javascript - you can just build object literals. It's quite a natural way to encapsulate code. Look at the difference between Components and FunctionComponents in React.js

Comment: `with(this) { loveJs = null; setLoveJS(true); }` ... but that's a terrible idea.